# how to update a custom listview

Tags: php, android, listview, android-listview

I have found a lot of approaches online but they haven't helped me, my questions is how can i add items to a listview without getting duplicate entries
 my php code is

```
$result1 = mysql_query("select * from headlines where categoryID = '$category' and newID = '$hashtagID' order by id DESC", $db->connect());
  $count = mysql_num_rows($result1);
  if($count != 0){
      $response["success"] = 1;

      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
          //getting user
          $result2 = mysql_query("select * from members where id = '".$row1['memberID']."'", $db->connect());
          while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
          $commentAuthor = $row2['last_name'];
          }

          $response['trends'][] = array('body'=>$row1['body'], 'name'=>$commentAuthor);

          }
      echo json_encode($response);


      }else{
          $response["success"] = 0;
          $response['trends'][] = array('body'=>'0', 'name'=>'0');
          echo json_encode($response);
          }
 }
```

and java code below am executing that background using async task

```
UserFunctions userfunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userfunction.loadhash(currenthash,
                categoryID);

        try {
            if (json.get(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                String rs = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(rs) == 1) {
                    istweetempty = true;
                    JSONArray arrayjson = json.getJSONArray("trends");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayjson.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject newobject = arrayjson.getJSONObject(i);
                        tweepList.add(0, newobject.getString("name")
                                .toString());
                        tweetList.add(0, newobject.getString("body")
                                .toString());
                    }

                } else {

                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and my problem is here, if i use `list_trending.setAdapter(tweets_adapter);` with `tweets_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` I get duplicate entries in my listview and if I use `tweets_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` only nothing happens to the listview and the new entries from the server dont appear. where could i be going wrong.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

        if (istweetempty == true) {
            tweepArray = tweepList.toArray(new String[tweepList.size()]);
            tweetArray = tweetList.toArray(new String[tweetList.size()]);
            tweets_adapter = new tweets(Trending.this, tweepArray,
                    tweetArray);
            //list_trending.setAdapter(tweets_adapter);
            tweets_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        list_trending.onRefreshComplete();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tweets_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i tried that and without the list_trending.setAdapter(tweets_adapter); nothing happens to the listview.